# Extension of double vertical line problem in the table

Tags: tables, bold

I would like to make $Des_e$ bold, and a vertical double line between $Des_e$ and $Des_o$. However I tried many times, I could not make it. Could you someone help me about it ?? thanks alot..

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{ch:five:sec:6:5:bitrate_saving}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l ||c |c || c |c} 
%\hline\hline
\it \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{MVV Sequence}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$Des_e$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$Des_o$} \\ %\cline{2-3}
 &\it $\Delta$R & \it $\Delta$P & \it $\Delta$R & \it $\Delta$P \\ \hline\hline
\textit{Bookarrival}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{Newspaper}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{ChampagneTower}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{Caf\'{e}}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{PoznanStreet} &-14.49$\%$ &-49.27$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{PoznanCarPark}&-25.46$\%$ &-21.94$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The table below labelled "First Version" gives you what you're requesting.

However, I would like to encourage you to consider creating a more open look to the table, by omitting all vertical lines, dropping the doubled horizontal line, and using the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to create well-spaced horizontal lines. The result of these changes is shown below in the Table labelled "Second Version".

Aside: I can't help but remark on what seems to be a bit of unusual TeX coding practice in the table labelled "First Version": all `%` symbols are rendered in math mode (why?), but the associated numbers are not -- causing all 24 "minus" symbols to be rendered incorrectly (typographically speaking) as short dashes. I suggest you either render the entire number (including any minus symbol) in math mode, or use a column type that processes its material in math mode automatically -- as is done in the second table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{multirow,amsmath,booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{First Version}
\label{ch:five:sec:6:5:bitrate_saving}

\begin{tabular}{l ||c |c || c |c} 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\itshape MVV Sequence}} 
   &\multicolumn{2}{c||}{$\textbf{\textit{Des}}_e$} 
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\textbf{\textit{Des}}_o$} \\ 
 &\it $\Delta$R & \it $\Delta$P & \it $\Delta$R & \it $\Delta$P \\ \hline\hline
\textit{Bookarrival}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{Newspaper}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{ChampagneTower}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{Caf\'{e}}&-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{PoznanStreet} &-14.49$\%$ &-49.27$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\textit{PoznanCarPark}&-25.46$\%$ &-21.94$\%$ &-79.14$\%$ &-49.99$\%$\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\caption{Second Version}
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{d{3.3}}} 
\toprule
\textbf{\itshape MVV Sequence} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{\bfseries\itshape{Des}}_e$} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\text{\bfseries\itshape{Des}}_o$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta R$} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta P$} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta R$} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta P$} \\
\midrule
\textit{Bookarrival}&-79.14\% &-49.99\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\textit{Newspaper}&-79.14\% &-49.99\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\textit{ChampagneTower}&-79.14\% &-49.99\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\textit{Caf\'{e}}&-79.14\% &-49.99\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\textit{PoznanStreet} &-14.49\% &-49.27\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\textit{PoznanCarPark}&-25.46\% &-21.94\% &-79.14\% &-49.99\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Answer user's question, then show them a better way.  Well played, sir.

Comment: @Mico `\text{\bfseries\itshape{Des}}` can be replaced by `\textbf{\textit{Des}}` or `\textit{\bfseries Des}`

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for noticing; I'll make the changes.

Comment: While your/booktabs's version undoubtedly looks much better, it seems rather tight.  Partly this is due to the 4SF precision (is it required?) and partly I think it could do with a little more space especially between the 2 pairs of numeric data columns.  This is of course subjective, and I understand space constraints may apply (I've probably gone too far in squeezing data in myself sometimes). +1 for many things but especially "use a proper numeric column".

Comment: @ChrisH - Thanks for these observations. One method for obtaining a bit more whitespace would be to specify `d{4.3}` instead of `d{4.3}` for the four data columns. (Not knowing what the overall space constraints of the OP's document may be, I opted for a minimalist option...)

Comment: Thanks. However, when i generate the table.  Illegal pream-token (4:3): 'c'  package array error is obtained for second table. Any idea ??

Comment: @Cagri - Did you load the `dcolumn` package and insert the instruction `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}` in the preamble? Note that the column specifier has to be of the form `d{3.3}`, not `d(3:3)`.

Comment: Yes, I just add and it works well !!. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely want double rules, you can have something cleaner (and a simpler code) with the `hhline` and `cellspace` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow,caption}
\usepackage{cellspace, hhline}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering\setlength\doublerulesep{3pt}
\label{ch:five:sec:6:5:bitrate_saving}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\itshape}Sl |*{2}{| >{$}c<{$}}|*{2}{|>{$}c<{$}}}
 \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{MVV Sequence}} &\multicolumn{2}{c||}{\boldmath$Des_e$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\boldmath$Des_o$} \\ %\cline{2-3}
 & \Delta R\ (\%)& \Delta P\ (\%) & \Delta R\ (\%) & \Delta P\ (\%) \\
 \hhline{=::==::==}
Bookarrival &-79.14 &-49.99 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
Newspaper &-79.14 &-49.99 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
ChampagneTower &-79.14 &-49.99 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
Café &-79.14 &-49.99 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
PoznanStreet &-14.49 &-49.27 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
PoznanCarPark &-25.46 &-21.94 &-79.14 &-49.99 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]